# Process exited with non-zero code: 1 at child process error while using expo init during creating React Native App

Tags: react-native

I have deleted `expo folder` and cleaned `npm cache` and again it is resulting the error upon creating react native app.

```
npm install -g expo-cli
expo init projectname
```

Error:

> Process exited with non-zero code: 1 at child process error while
>   using expo init during creating React Native App

Answer (score 3):

Just i have solved this issue with bellow command.

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

[Fore more details](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/318)

Answer (score 1):

npm exited with non-zero code: 4294967291

this error was solved on Windows

open the cmd as administrator

then run command:

```
npm install -g npm
```